# UIWebView not won't "scrollsToTop" on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7

I have two `UIWebView` in a single `ViewController` in order to preload one in the background for the "next page".

Since opening the project in Xcode 5, these no longer scroll to the top when the status bar is tapped.

The App is otherwise working fine with iOS 7 so I don't know what's wrong. When one of the `UIWebView` is hidden, I also `setScrollsToTop:NO` ... so there's clearly something I'm missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just interface builder.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a simple class for this specific issue. In my app we're having multiple webviews and scrollviews. This makes it all much easier.

https://gist.github.com/hfossli/6776203

Comment: The solution I found honestly was just to listen for the top 20px "tap" area and scroll anything with a "scroll" ability to the top with animated set to YES. It's not pretty but it works. — I'll check out your solution next time I run into this issue.

Comment: That's an interesting approach :)

Comment: @ancajic Well, did you do excactly as in the gist? Including methodcall in appdelegate? Can you create a demo-project?

Comment: you've got to give me more information if I am to help you.

Comment: It's ok, I opted out of using category and made it to work. But I am sure it would work with category also. I must have configured the scroll view delegate methods wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this category:

*UIView+LogViewHierarchy.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (LogViewHierarchy)

-(void) logViewHierarchy;

@end
```

*UIView+LogViewHierarchy.m*

```
#import "UIView+LogViewHierarchy.h"

@implementation UIView (LogViewHierarchy)


-(void) logViewHierarchy
{

    NSLog(@"%@%@", NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    [self logSubviews:self depth:1];
}

-(void) logSubviews:(UIView*)view depth:(NSInteger)depth
{
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@%@%@ - scrollsToTop: %@", [self paddingString:depth], NSStringFromClass(subview.class), NSStringFromCGRect(subview.frame), ((UIScrollView*)subview).scrollsToTop ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@%@%@", [self paddingString:depth], NSStringFromClass(subview.class), NSStringFromCGRect(subview.frame));
        }
        [self logSubviews:subview depth:depth+1];
    }
}

-(NSString*) paddingString:(NSInteger)depth
{
    return [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:depth*2 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
}


@end
```

Then find your app's root view controller and add:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view logViewHierarchy];
}
```

You will be able to see all UIScrollViews and their `scrollsToTop` properties. When you manage to make your output look like there is only 1 UIScrollView that has `scrollsToTop == YES`, then your *scrollsToTop* gesture should work fine.

In my case, `logViewHierarchy` reported that all your scroll views have `scrollsToTop = NO`, and you didn't know why, because I explicitly set them to `YES`.
It turned out that I left [this UIScrollView category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113218/1639049) inside my project, and it overloaded some methods on all my UIScrollViews. When I removed that category from my project, I was able to get correct output from `logViewHierarchy`. Then I played around with code until I managed to get only one `scrollsToTop = YES`.